# applying sort commands to many files one by one

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have many files 1.txt, 2.txt, ... 100.txt.

I want to sort data in each file like sort -n 1.txt > 1_sorted.txt

I want to know how to do it with many files by simple commands.

Comment: why not put all the files data into one file and sort the resultant file  ?

Comment: That's not the case for me. Each file is independent data, e.g. line profile.

Comment: Do you definitely need to rename the files?  A simple script like `for file in "$@"; do sort -n "$file" > "$(basename "$file" .txt)_sorted.txt"; done` will do the job given a list of file names.  You can then use this script with `find` or `xargs` or by any other method of your choosing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run shell scrip as below.(sort.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.txt
do
sort -n  "$f" > "sorted_$f"
done
```

run this with in current folder and with execution permissions (chmod +x sort.sh)

Comment: Replace `> "sorted_$f"` by `-o "sorted_$f"` to avoid a pipe.

Answer (score 3):

This will allow you to parallelise the sorting using [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
parallel sort {} -o {.}_sorted.txt ::: *.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. Taken them out - I got into the habit of using them for expansions with spaces, but it does work without.

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple `for` loop:

```
for f in {1..100}; do
    sort -n "$f.txt" > "${f}_sorted.txt"
done
```

Comment: Replace `> "sorted_$f"` by `-o "sorted_$f"` to avoid a pipe.

Comment: That's not a pipe. It's just an output redirection.

Answer (score 1):

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*.txt -print0 |
   xargs -0 -n 1 -I{} bash -c 'sort -n {} > `basename -s .txt {}`_sorted.txt'
```

Comment: You'd have to put the `-c` script in single quotes or the back-quotes will be executed far too soon (before `xargs` is executed).

Comment: The `-o` option to sort lets you use the `-exec` primary instead of `xargs`: `find ... -exec sort -n {} -o {}_sorted.txt \;`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've edited to fix the quotes.  @chepner, I couldn't find a way to strip the .txt suffix (so I don't get .txt_sorted.txt) without using something more than `find`.  Thanks to both of you.